# oracle: query to output delimited IDs as reference codes

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table with a tree structure of business units.

```
BUT_ID  PARENT_ID  REFERENCE_CODE  BUT_PATH
173     10         SBT022          /1/2/10/173
174     8          SEM05000        /1/2/8/174
175     10         SBT023          /1/2/10/175
2       1          O               /1/2
8       2          SP              /1/2/8
1       null       root            null
```

Where `BUT_PATH` is a path in the business tree to the current business unit.

I got stuck writing a query to output the `BUT_PATH` structure with the corresponding reference codes instead of ids. For example, for `/1/2/8/174` it would be like `/O/SP/SEM05000` in Oracle 12c.

Comment: explain why you like `/O/SP/SEM/SEM05000` as result

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza: This is not about my preferences, it is requested by the customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this by first creating as many copies of a row as there are nodes in the path. That can be done by joining the table with itself using the `ROWNUM` pseudo column -- join on `ROWNUM <=` the number of nodes in the path, which we can extract by using `REGEXP_COUNT()` to count the `/`.

For each path with *n* nodes we now have *n* rows with a number `RN` from 1 to *n*. With `REGEXP_REPLACE()` we can extract the ID of the `RN`th node from the path.

We once again join the table, this time using that `RN`th ID from the path. Like that we have the reference of the `RN`th node in the respective row.

Finally we aggregate and use `LISTAGG()` to put the path of references together.

```
SELECT T1.BUT_ID,
       T1.PARENT_ID,
       T1.REFERENCE_CODE,
       T1.BUT_PATH,
       '/' || LISTAGG(T3.REFERENCE_CODE, '/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY X1.RN) REFERENCE_PATH
       FROM ELBAT T1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT ROWNUM RN
                               FROM ELBAT T2) X1
                       ON X1.RN <= REGEXP_COUNT(T1.BUT_PATH, '/')
            INNER JOIN ELBAT T3
                       ON T3.BUT_ID = TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(T1.BUT_PATH, '/[^/]+', 1, X1.RN), '^/'))
       GROUP BY T1.BUT_ID,
                T1.PARENT_ID,
                T1.REFERENCE_CODE,
                T1.BUT_PATH;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2285fa04e35b722ce7d4eefadd22aa24)